# Strange behaviour inside Email Editor

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio

Recently (nothing changed on our templates) the email studio of marketing cloud extends the view of certain content blocks when you click on them. They show content even across the area which is editable in emails.

First Screenshot (when you have clicked nothing):
[image]

Second Screenshot when you clicked on a content block(with the arrow and ? created by myself):
[image]

Has anybody experienced the same problem? Is there something you can do about it? (the emails are not affected only the view when you edit or create emails).
( I am sorry that i had to use the black squares, but i cannot show customer content here)

Comment: Are you using a dymamic content block by any chance? (i.e. the UI widget in Content Builder)

Comment: Yes we do use dynamic content blocks, both of the blocks are dynamic ones.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of dynamic content blocks changed in the latest release.

In the previous release, dynamic content rules were created using GTL tags and helpers, but now they have been changed to AMPscript. If you switch to the code view (you may have to toggle the control to show full HTML), you will see the AMPscript that's being generated.

Specifically, a mix of AMPscript blocks and inline AMPscript are now inserted, as per the example below.

You would/should be seeing this AMPscript in edit mode, but perhaps your style is using the a text or background color that is the same as the code. Anyway, I'm pretty sure you will find this is the culprit.

Looks like its a UI bug that Salesforce need to address (given that it didn't occur in the previous release).

```js
%%[IF (([Product] == "phone")) THEN]%%
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("01__Rule_1__1001572095.jpg")=%%
   <img src="http://image.s6.exacttarget.com/lib/fe891274746c0d7c7c/m/1/bf197636-a694-4e52-b2ec-8aafa91d1abf.jpg" data-assetid="20491" alt="1001572095.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
%%=EndImpressionRegion()=%%
%%[ELSE]%%
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("01__Default_Content__1001510255.jpg")=%%
   <img src="http://image.s6.exacttarget.com/lib/fe891274746c0d7c7c/m/1/a4e49747-6d5d-480f-8c2f-c7c425bdf3a5.jpg" data-assetid="20493" alt="1001510255.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
%%=EndImpressionRegion()=%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```